# Which 3.3V I/O standard should I use?

Tags: adc, pins, quartus-ii

I am using the Altera Quartus II PinPlanner to enter all my pin details for my FPGA design. Some of the pins are connected to the SPI configuration bus of [this ADC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads6143.pdf).

As can be seen on page 8, the 3 pins `SCLK`, `SDATA`, and `SEN` must be driven at 3.3V. Now the pin planner gives me three different 3.3V options:

- 3.3V LVCMOS
- 3.3V LVTTL
- 3.3V PCML

Which of these I/O standards should I use for my ADC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you see a V<sub>IH</sub> specification of 2.4 V and V<sub>IL</sub> of 0.8 V — i.e., fixed voltages, not a fraction of the supply voltage — that's LVTTL.